# Unable to display Arabic content in Powershell window

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, arabic-support

We have a script with Arabic characters.

**Input:**

```
write-output "Testing Arabic language input"
$x=@"
كاتريونا الرمادي
"@
Write-output $x
```

**Output:**

> ```
> ####START####
> Testing Arabic language input
> ÙƒØ§ØªØ±ÙŠÙˆÙ†Ø§ Ø§Ù„Ø±Ù…Ø§Ø¯ÙŠ
> ####END####
> ```

This content is not displayed properly.

Any specific way to Encode, so that Arabic characters can be displayed.
Issue exists for all non english characters.

Comment: See; [Using UTF-8 Encoding (CHCP 65001) in Command Prompt / Windows Powershell (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/1701026)

Comment: You need to use the correct FONT.  Try : You can change the font that PowerShell uses by right-clicking the title bar and going to Properties or Default. There's a Font tab in the window that opens where you can select a font and its size.

Comment: Make sure your ps1 script is saved using utf8 with BOM encoding

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: ```[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( 1252).GetString( [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( 'UTF-8').GetBytes( 'كاتريونا الرمادي'))``` returns ```ÙƒØ§ØªØ±ÙŠÙˆÙ†Ø§ Ø§Ù„Ø±Ù…Ø§Ø¯ÙŠ```… *The same example in Python is universally intelligible*): `'كاتريونا الرمادي'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'ÙƒØ§ØªØ±ÙŠÙˆÙ†Ø§ Ø§Ù„Ø±Ù…Ø§Ø¯ÙŠ'`.